# pydev debugger gives error on breakpoint

Tags: python, debugging, pytest

While running an end to end test I get the following error only when the execution stops at a breakpoint. the test does pass after I resume it. Also if I dont put a breakpoint the then also the test passes. I am guessing it has something to with the intellij and pydev settings.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ckhanna\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 354, in evaluate_expression
    compiled = compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')
  File "<string>", line 1
    args.0
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ckhanna\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1125, in do_it
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Users\ckhanna\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 356, in evaluate_expression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "C:\Users\ckhanna\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 1
    args.0
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
NameError: name '__py_debug_temp_var_1721695151' is not defined
```

Comment: We need to see the code that the traceback is referring to. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Running into this as well with PyCharm 2017.1.2. Did you report this directly to JetBrains? Pretty sure this is a bug.

Comment: I have a same problem. Could you solve it ?